# Play too many arguments for method Apply

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am doing a Play2 and Scala tutorial from Pluralsight.

I created a default project and I configured it this way:

controller `Application.scala`

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Hello, again, world!"))
  }

}
```

view `index.scala.html`

```
(@message: String)
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Play 2 for Scala!
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>
            @message
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have the following route in my route file:

```
GET      /                          controllers.Application.index
```

My issue is that when I try to access `http://localhost:9000/`, I get:

```
too many arguments for method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class index

6class Application extends Controller {
7
8  def index = Action {
9    Ok(views.html.index("Hello, again, world!")) 
10  }
11
12}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameter list that you declared in your view is wrong

```
(@message: String)
```

It should be

```
@(message: String)
```